# Page numbering is one off in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I know there are a lot of questions on this already. I have tried the solutions from those, they don't work. I'm writing my thesis in the `report` class. The first few pages are roman numerals and everything after the list of figures should be arabic numbers. However, the second page of list of figures is numbered as 1. The Preface is numbered 2 but shows up in the ToC as 1. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper, margin = 1in}
\usepackage{pdfpages, subfiles}
\begin{document}
\subfile{Others/cover}
\subfile{Others/Quote}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\subfile{Others/Acknowledgements}

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\subfile{Others/Preface}
\subfile{Sections/Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Please suggest what I can do to fix the pagenumbering and have it show correctly in the ToC. Thanks!

Comment: Your document is of course not compilable since `\subfile` is an unknown command; and even if it would be known, the relevant files are not available to us

Comment: Sorry I added the right package but I don't know to fix the other issue. I can't share the file, and I wanted to describe how I was adding sections in.

Comment: Try to add a `\clearpage` after `\listoffigures`. Perhaps that cures the problem

Comment: Rather `\cleardoublepage`, just in case you are switching to `twoside` in the future.

Comment: @Johannes_B: ... just in case...

Comment: @TeXnician I voted to close as duplicate.